# How do I remove the ugly border around CALayer with cornerradius?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-animation, swift

I'm drawing a simple line chart using Core Graphics. I've created a custom class `LineChart` which inherits from `UIControl`. On top of this chart I'd like to add a small filled circle that will be animated (change border color) on touch.

Here is the code for my circles at each (x,y) point.

```
var layer = CALayer()
layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
layer.cornerRadius = 8
layer.borderWidth = 4
layer.frame = CGRect(x: xValue, y: yValue, width: 16, height: 16)
self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

I'd like to have a black center with a white border. The problem is that I have a tiny ugly black border around my outer white border.

[image: tiny ugly border around CALayer]

How can I get rid of this border? I've played with antialiasing settings or added some Core Graphics with a small 1px white border on top but both didn't work out. The black background always shined through and created this outer border. I've seen [CALayer Border strange issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022842/calayer-border-strange-issue) but cannot believe that I really have to add two layers at each data point.

Comment: Here's a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073224/uiview-with-rounded-corner-and-border-has-wrong-edge-color). I know of no way to solve the issue, other than to offer a kludgy work around. However, since I haven't bothered with `swift`, my answer would be in `objective-C`. Interested?

Comment: Sure, `Objective-C` is totally fine.

Comment: This answer is right. Better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073224/uiview-with-rounded-corner-and-border-has-wrong-edge-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to work around the problem is to create a custom subclass of `CALayer` and override the `drawInContext` method to draw the bordered circle.  Here's the class implementation

```
@implementation DotLayer

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self )
    {
        self.frame = frame;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        self.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    return( self );
}

- (void)setBorderColor:(CGColorRef)borderColor
{
    [super setBorderColor:borderColor];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, self.borderColor );
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect( context, rect );

    rect = CGRectInset( self.bounds, 4, 4 );
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor );
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect( context, rect );
}

@end
```

Here's the code to add a dot

```
    DotLayer *layer = [[DotLayer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( xValue, yValue, 16, 16 )];
    [self.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

And here's the code to change the border color of a dot

```
    layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: How do I change the outer border color (in my case the white border) on touch events? With your solution I'd have to draw another circle on top of the existing ones, right? I'd like to reuse already existing elements and simply change properties, like `myLayersArray[1].backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor`

Comment: @zemirco -- Good point. I've modified the answer to allow changing the white circle to a different color by using the layer's `borderColor` property.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I chose two separate layers - https://github.com/zemirco/swift-linechart/blob/master/linechart/linechart/LineChart.swift#L227